# Sending data from c to perl

Tags: c, linux, perl, shared-memory

I need to send some data from c program to Perl program that both in running mode (Perl program in sleep mode and c program running, and c program sends data to Perl).

I know that, can write this program by socket and shared memory but I have performance problem. I think shared memory is better solution, and how can I signal to Perl program to wake up and resume run and read data that c send?

Answer (score 7):

You seem to have two questions here:

1. how to share memory between the Perl program and your C program, and
2. how to signal the Perl program there is new data available

Assuming you're on a system that allows SysV IPC calls, you can use [IPC::ShareLite](http://search.cpan.org/dist/IPC-ShareLite/) to share a chunk of memory between the two processes.

As usual with shared memory, you will have to ensure locks are in place. The module manual page for IPC::ShareLite seems to explain the intricacies and the method calls fairly well.

Regarding signaling the Perl program there is new data available, there's nothing stopping you from using... signals to achieve that! Your C program can send a SIGUSR1 to the Perl program, and the Perl program will access the shared memory and do stuff when receiving the signal, and sleep otherwise.

Have a look at [perldoc perlipc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlipc.html) for that, but the gist of it is something along these lines:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use IPC::ShareLite;

# init shared memory

sub do_work {
    # use shared memory, as you just received a signal
    # indicating there's new data available
    my $signame = shift;
    # ...
}
$SIG{USR1} = \&do_work; # when signaled with SIGUSR1, call do_work()

# else just sleep
while(1) { sleep 1; }
```

Hope this helps,

-marco-

Comment: Given that the OP is concerned enough about performance to consider using shared memory instead of unix sockets, I wonder how well signals do in that regard?

Answer (score 3):

- Have a look on topic :**"Embedding
  Perl (Using Perl from C)"**-Chapter 21
  Perl Programming Third Edition -
  Larry wall
- See **[Internals and C language
  interface](http://perldoc.perl.org/index-internals.html)** specially this
  part-**Perl calling conventions from
  C**.

  Then, you will come to know how
  to send data efficiently
  between C and Perl Program.

Answer (score 2):

Use a database like MySql.

If you're that worried about performance implement the perl code in C, or vice versa.

Answer (score 2):

Use a database like *SQLite*, then you don't need to install database server.

SQLite Library:  http://metacpan.org/pod/DBD::SQLite

Answer (score 1):

You keep referring to "performance problem".

Could you please be more specific about exactly what your performance requirements are?  We need to know this before we can suggest an optimal solution.  Otherwise, we're just guessing.

In the "guessing" category, I would recommend:

- pipes
- database

Either of these alternatives would be excellent alternatives in a vast majority of "real world" scenarios I could think of.

We definitely need more details about your particular scenario.

Thank you in advance .. PSM

Comment: To explain: it would be nice to have some idea of why the program is slow: does it keep the CPU busy at 100%?  Does reading and writing data take too much time?  Do you run out of memory?